# Flask Apps in subdirectories

Tags: python, flask

I'm running two Flask-Apps on my server simultaneously. Now I wanted to make a `run.py`in their parent directory to serve all of their routes.
This is the structure:

```
| - run.py
| - app1/
|    |- app1.py
|    |- static
|    |- templates
| - app2/
|    |- app2.py
|    |- static
|    |- templates
```

Each of the Apps have their own routes.
My question is:
What do I have to write into the `run.py`-File so that when I browse to `the_url\app1\` I get the `'/'`-route of my `app1.py`?
And what do I have to write so that `the_url/app1/some/url` leads me to the `/some/url`-route of my app1 (and app2)

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, what your *exact* problem is:

> I'm running two Flask-Apps on my server simultaneously.

According to this, you mean: »I am running *AppA* on *port abcd* and another *AppB* on *port efgh*«. This requires two independently running python processes, each with its own *run.py*.

---

What you could do is, when the two are "releated" somehow, that you use [Blueprints](https://exploreflask.com/en/latest/blueprints.html). Blueprints make it possible to separate functionality within *one* flask app: so this means, when the two share the same users etc. you could throw them together in one app.

The routes could be registered

```
app1 = Blueprint('app1', __name__, url_prefix='/app1')
app2 = Blueprint('app2', __name__, url_prefix='/app2')
```

The separation could be managed with *permissions*.